# Lazy property loading in Nhibernate and Spring

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2 and Spring 1.3

I have two Text columns (blobs) in one of my classes. I'm trying to use lazy="true" for the mapping of those properties but NHProfiler still shows the two columns being added to the SELECT statement when the main object is loaded.

I'm using Spring.NHibernate session factory and have configured ProxyFactory with both Castle and Spring with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I know that's something NOT included on the version 2.1.2

According this url, lazy properties is something quite new and it's already on the trunk ready to be released on next version

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx

You can download the current trunk code or wait to 3.0 version :-)

https://nhibernate.jira.com/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10000&version=10293