# NHibernate - is property lazy loading possible?

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I've got some binary data that I store and was going to separate this out into a separate table so it could be lazy loaded.

However, i then came across this post by Ayende (http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx) which suggests that property lazy loading is now possible.

I have added the lazy="true" attribute to my property mapping but the field is still loaded from the database (I am using a simple text field to test).

My query:

```
                return _session.CreateQuery("from Product")
                .SetMaxResults(1)
                .UniqueResult<Product>();
```

Mapping:

```
<property name="Description" type="string" column="FullDescription" lazy="true"/>
```

Has anyone been able to get this working? Personally I prefer this approach than having to add another table to my database.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773871/nhibernate-lazy-properties-behavior/2774569#2774569

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the article states: "This feature is now available on the NHibernate trunk". So either NH 3.0 or [the latest trunk](https://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/).

Answer (score 2):

It will be possible on nhibernate 3.0, on the current version is not possible. You can download the trunk code or wait for the 3.0 version :-)